# AngularJS - valores de select de acordo de outro select

Tags: angularjs

Sou nova em AngularJS e como estou começando ainda tenho muitas dúvidas...
Gostaria de saber como fazer um  secundário ter valores de acordo a um  primário, como nesses sites de carros, você seleciona a marca e os modelos aparecem de acordo com a marca escolhida.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir um ngChange para quando for alterado o valor do primeiro select.

```
<select ng-model="marca" ng-options="marca.id as marca.nome 
    for marca in marcas" ng-change="CarregarModelo(marca)">
    <option value="">Selecione a Marca</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="modelo" ng-options="modelo.id as modelo.nome 
    for modelo in modelos">
    <option value="">Selecione o Modelo</option>
</select>
```

E no controller você cria a função do ng-change para listar no segundo select.

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.CarregarModelo = function(marca){
       $http.get(url).success(function(res){
           $scope.modelo = res.data;
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Flávio.
Eu posso colocar as duas funções (CarregarMarcar e CarregarModelo) no mesmo Controller?

Comment: Pode sim, sem problemas.